# Webview loading outside screen?

Tags: android, android-emulator

This code was working with another aspx form, now when I changed the form, it works in blackberry's webview however the android now boots a external browser, even know before it booted within the application.

```
webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setInitialScale (5); 
    webview.loadUrl(URL);
    webview.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

why is it loading outside the browser now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to implement `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` . A snippet from my recent project:

```
public class WebViewCustom extends Activity {

WebView mWebView;
String mUrl;
String urlHistory;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.lessons_page);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewOverrideUrl());
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("YOUR-URL-HERE");


    }

       private class WebViewOverrideUrl extends WebViewClient {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        }
```

}

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, your server is issuing a redirect. If you implement a `WebViewClient` and have it override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`, you can force the redirect to be loaded in the `WebView` itself.